# Is a Processing language a good tool for prototyping?

Tags: prototype

I'm a UX designer who use Axure RP PRO and some bits of JS while I'm making mobile prototypes, but recently I'm thinking about Processing language to use it to make simple mobile prototypes with animations.

Does anybody use processing in this way? Is a processing a right tool for this kind of activity?

Answer (score 2):

Small point of clarity - you would have to use http://p5js.org/ because you'll need HTML5 Canvas and WebGL for rendering. I could be wrong on this, but I don't think so.

But why do this? What are you looking for that can't be done in a prototyping tool? I don't want to discourage you from learning something new, but this would be a lot of work for a design that's not completed. You really need to be able to cycle the process of "design - prototype - change" and repeat until you're ready to build. Maybe your looking to build a new prototyping tool? If that's it, then go for it! Good luck, keep us up to date, I'd love to see it.

Comment: BTW, did you know that Axure Beta 8 will have some pretty sweet animation tools? http://www.axure.com/c/blog/162-learn-axure-rp-8-beta-new-actions-animations.html

Comment: Yes, I would expect to see something like Tumult Hype at the beginning of a workflow and Processing at the end.

Comment: @bryandavidk Well I would like to explore some new ways to do things, in Axure sometimes it is harder to achieve some results especially much more interactive solutions than in live code e.g. making slider control with corresponding text field and making it both interacting with each other is much easier to prototype with jQuery than to figure out how to do this in Axure. Processing is also a quite good way to learn basic code concepts and play with animation.